# Trying to set a transparent navbar but it shows up black

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

I have been trying to get a transparent `navigationBar` but it becomes black.
Here is the code i used to make it transparent:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
```

Any help is much appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this `UINavigationBar` extension

**Use**

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.makeTransparent()
```

*Extension*

```
public extension UINavigationBar {

    /// - Parameter tint: tint color (default is .white).
    public func makeTransparent(withTint tint: UIColor = .white) {
        setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        shadowImage = UIImage()
        isTranslucent = true
        tintColor = tint
        titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: tint]
    }

}
```

Comment: hey. @AshvinGudaliya I am doing the same thing if you note the code above. Moreover i tried your out too, still get a black bar.

Comment: You can checkout navigationController is a value or nil

Comment: oh.. its a value for sure. Otherwise the code of changing it wouldn't have worked.

Comment: Please check out your screenshot. first image X is upside to a black bar. maybe change you Constraint. navigation is hidden but mistake in Constraint

Comment: Basically the issue is when the keyboard comes up the logo hides behind the navigationBar. To remedy that i wanted a transparent navbar so the logo can be seen completely.

Comment: Right now the top of the content is constraint to safe Area, i tried to change it to the top of superview too. Still get the same

Comment: That might be difficult to share the whole thing, basically before setting viewController (using navController.setViewControllers( , animated:) on a navController, i'm setting the properties as mentioned above in the post